# Add programmatically to window created by pyuic from qt-designer ui file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have looked at the answer to this previous question  "Access QT Designer Objects Programmatically". It is the question I am asking but this answer just recodes the window without reference to the module generated by pyuic. So, is it possible to say create a blank window in qt-designer, its pyuic file and then manipulate that window, adding widgets etc from your own python class. If it is possible can anyone point me to an example? Thanks

my .ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>mainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="mainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>161</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>3</number>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

```py
from mydesign import Ui_mainWindow

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(mywindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_mainWindow()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        pixmap = QPixmap('image.jpeg')
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(500)
        self.ui.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToWidth(64)

        #I want to add this widget to window in Ui_mainWindow - Is this possible?
        #This code produces a separate SVG window. 
        self.ui.svgWidget = QSvgWidget('GT.svg')
        self.ui.svgWidget.setGeometry(0,0,730,300)
        self.ui.svgWidget.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

application = mywindow()

application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add something you must know where it is going to be added, assuming that the .ui is an empty design:

*.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Then you convert it to .py with the help of pyuic:

```
pyuic5 foo_filename.ui -o design.py -x
```

Considering the above it is not necessary to add anything to the Ui_mainWindow since it is not a widget, it is a class that is used to fill a widget, so what you should do is add it to the window. In this case, as it is a QMainWindow you must use the centralwidget:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSvg

from design import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpeg")
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(500)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget("GT.svg")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget())
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        lay.addWidget(self.svgWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Update

Because you have provided the .ui then the solution is modified. For a widget to be displayed in a window it must be a child of the window or the child of a child in the window, in this case a centralwidget is used.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSvg

from design import Ui_mainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpeg")
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(500)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget("GT.svg", parent=self.centralWidget())
        self.svgWidget.setGeometry(0, 0, 730, 300)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. This certainly does what I want though I'm not sure why, yet.

Comment: @user11443269 If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour]

Comment: I've just seen that my code puts the jpeg on the label generated by qt-designer but your answer must make a new label for the jpeg. How do I interact with the qt-designer label. I will check Tour.

Comment: @user11443269 Provide your .ui, since as you see the answer depends on your design.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I need. I don't understand yet but will study your code in detail.